# Why os.Create can not written with io.Copy?

Tags: go

I was trying to make a post-data request in Golang.

Fist time I made a temp file to attach a file to API.

That creates with os.Create and try to write a form object with os.Create but written byte got zero.

So when I Colose the file then I re-open that and did the os.Create, that was worked.

So, the question is why I couldn't copy the byte directly with os.Create?

Here is my example code, I really appreciate that if you explain that.

Demo in Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/-IRJPn--umd

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Seek` to set the start of the next read to the beginning of the file before the copy:

```golang
if _, err := tmpFile.Seek(0, io.SeekStart); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

if ioWriter, err = w.CreateFormFile("file", tmpFile.Name()); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var writtenCopy int64
if writtenCopy, err = io.Copy(ioWriter, tmpFile); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```